# is it possible to point one asp.net core application to 2 app insights instances

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-monitoring, appinsights

i have a situation where i have bunch of already existing asp.net core apps pointed to to their specific app insights instances.

i want all of them to point to another app insights to send a very specific type of logging data without breaking their relation with the app insights instance they are already pointed to.

So is it possible to some how dependency inject 2 different app insights in one application ?

How i understand is that we simply inject AppInsights once like below.

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

and the we can give instrumentation key in the app settings.

```
"ApplicationInsights": {  
   "InstrumentationKey": "Copy paste"  
 }
```

i am open to any other suggestion to solve this problem aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can  initialize 2 different Application Insights object based on 2 different keys & utilize them to track different telemetry.

However you can see the recommendation on when to use single resource according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/separate-resources#when-to-use-a-single-application-insights-resource),